# htaccess - mod_rewrite pass virtual directory or file back to index.php as parameter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I'm trying to get a virtual directory or file to be passed back to index.php

Example, I want everything after the / to get passed back to index, which will then be checked against a database, but "virtual_directory" and "virtual_file.jpg" don't actually exist, they are just parameters.

```
somedomain.com/virtual_directory
somedomain.com/virtual_file.jpg
```

Now, the problem is that *EVERYTHING* passes. So say I just want to go to the main directory (or just index.php) I would type in the url (somedomain.com) and it would pass the trailing slash as a parameter. It is also the same if I try to go to somedomain.com/index.php. It will pass with /index.php (ie: I cannot get to the else statement).

Is there a way to make it so it will not pass if I am directly going to the index?

These two will pass as a parameter, and I do not want them too.

```
somedomain.com/
somedomain.com/index.php
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

index.php will read what was after the '/' and do something with it.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    echo nl2br("Parameter Passed!\n");
    echo 'Parameter That Passed:' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} else{
    echo 'No Parameter Passed';
    echo 'You Are Visiting domain.com/ or domain.com/index.php';
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Added a problem. I somehow forgot to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the "else" part of your php code isn't being reached is because **there will always be** a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value. This is a server variable that will always be *the request*. Thus, you'll never get to "no parameter passed". What you may want instead if to either pass the parameter as a GET variable or as PATH INFO:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

and your code would be:

```
if ($_GET['request']) {
    echo nl2br("Parameter Passed!\n");
    echo 'Parameter That Passed:' .$_GET['request'];
} else{
    echo 'No Parameter Passed';
    echo 'You Are Visiting domain.com/ or domain.com/index.php';
}
```

or pathinfo:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and your code would be:

```
if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
    echo nl2br("Parameter Passed!\n");
    echo 'Parameter That Passed:' .$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
} else{
    echo 'No Parameter Passed';
    echo 'You Are Visiting domain.com/ or domain.com/index.php';
}
```

Comment: 12shadow12's use of words was funny... I just came to write "beautiful answer."  Well done, Jon Lin, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```